# Как для Google app изменить права доступа к SpreadSheet c "чтения" на "запись и чтение"?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Где-то пол года назад на Google Cloud Platform зарегистрировал приложение которое работает с Google Sheets API. Всё это время моё десктопное приложение читало информацию из гугл таблиц, но теперь мне понадобилось записывать данные, но доступ у меня есть только на чтение. Я не знаю как изменить приложение на Google Cloud Platform и можно ли это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что это регулируется не только в настройках приложения на Google Cloud Platform.
В самом коде я ошибочно указывал

```
string[] scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
```

а надо было

```
string[] scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
```